# Elements of paper

Tags: everyday-chemistry, elemental-analysis

I learnt that everything is made up of atoms even paper! After that, I was thinking what are the elements that made paper? Is there any chemical symbol for paper in general?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no chemical symbol for paper since it is not an element but rather a mixture of several different compounds.

Remember that paper is made out of trees. Thus, paper is made mostly out of organic compounds: that is carbon, hydrogen and oxygen (C, H and O). Paper also contains non organic materials to improve its properties. These may be chalk (CaCO<sub>3</sub>) and kaolin clay (Al<sub>2</sub>Si<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub>(OH)<sub>4</sub>). Titanium oxide (TiO<sub>2</sub>) is also commonly used in paper for bleaching it.

Comment: Titanium dioxide doesn't *bleach* paper: it whitens it by making it more opaque via scattering from the small oxide particles. Other bleaches like hypochlorite *are* used to removed coloured impurities from the wood pulp components.

Comment: Correct - I was using bleaching in the optical sense, not the chemical sense.